# In Dropwizard 0.8.4, how do you make use of the rolesAllowed annotation?

Tags: java, dropwizard

In new dropwizard versions you can create a basic auth filter that takes an authorizor and authenticator. Then each resource can be annotated with an `@RolesAllowed` tag.

In 0.8.4 you can't create an authorizer the same way - but the `RolesAllowed` tag remains. How do you use the `rolesAllowed` tag to get the same behavior as seen in later versions?

Comment: [Dropwizard 0.8.4](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/v0.8.4) was released on 26 Aug 2015. Is there any reason why you want to a version that is almost three years old?

Comment: Mostly a legacy issue that will be resolved soon enough. But in the meantime I'm restricted to this version, and I'm curious because the mere existence of the #RolesAllowed annotation along with the RolesAllowedDynamicFeature in this version implies (to me) that you don't need to inject an #Auth user into each resource to check roles.

Comment: Those (@RolesAllowed and RolesAllowedDynamicFeature) are Jersey features and not Dropwizard's. Dropwizard didn't make use of them prior to 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dropwizard 0.8.x it's not possible to use the `@RolesAllowed` because of the way the authentication is done; it doesn't tie into how Jersey uses the `SecurityContext`. Starting 0.9.0 is when Dropwizard started using the `SecurityContext`, which is what Jersey uses to make the `@RolesAllowed` annotation work.

Luckily, you can just upgrade the `dropwizard-auth` dependency to 0.9.0 and it will still work with Dropwizard 0.8.4. I've actually just tested this and it works fine. You just need to exclude the `dropwizard-core` from it.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After doing this, it should all work. I'll post all the classes that I used to test it.

#### `ExamplePrincipal`

```
public class ExamplePrincipal implements Principal {
    private String name;
    private List<String> roles;

    public ExamplePrincipal(String name, List<String> roles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return this.roles;
    }
}
```

#### `ExampleAuthenticator`

```
public class ExampleAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, ExamplePrincipal> {

    @Override
    public Optional<ExamplePrincipal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {
        if ("peeskillet".equals(credentials.getUsername())
                && "secret".equals(credentials.getPassword())) {
            return Optional.of(new ExamplePrincipal(credentials.getUsername(), Arrays.asList("ADMIN")));
        }
        return Optional.absent();
    }
}
```

#### `ExampleAuthorizer`

```
public class ExampleAuthorizer implements Authorizer<ExamplePrincipal> {

    @Override
    public boolean authorize(ExamplePrincipal principal, String role) {
        return principal.getRoles().contains(role);
    }
}
```

#### `ExampleResource`

```
@Path("example")
public class ExampleResource {

    private String name;

    public ExampleResource(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    public String get() {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("root")
    @RolesAllowed("ROOT")
    public String getRoot() {
        return "Root Access";
    }
}
```

#### `ExampleConfiguration`

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {

    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### `ExampleApplication`

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application<ExampleConfiguration> {

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        new ExampleApplication().run(args);
    }


    public void run(ExampleConfiguration config, Environment env) throws Exception {
        env.jersey().property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
        env.jersey().register(new ExampleResource(config.getName()));

        env.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        env.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
                new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<ExamplePrincipal>()
                        .setAuthenticator(new ExampleAuthenticator())
                        .setAuthorizer(new ExampleAuthorizer())
                        .setRealm("ExampleRealm")
                        .buildAuthFilter()
        ));
        env.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<ExamplePrincipal>(ExamplePrincipal.class));
    }
}
```

#### `example.yml`

```
name: "Peeskillet"
```

To test the application you can just run the following cURL command

```
curl -i -u peeskillet:secret http://locahost:8080/example
```

If you go to the `example/root` endpoint where a `ROOT` user is required, you will see 403 Forbidden response

```
url -i -u peeskillet:secret http://locahost:8080/example/root
```